# JavaScript click and tap detection IOS, Browser

Tags: javascript

In 2018 what is the best way of simply detecting a "click" or mobile "tap" event, it has to be native, not reliant of a framework, or could be a small foot print library. The only one I can find is [hammerjs](https://hammerjs.github.io/) which seem overkill for just tap and click detection.

I'm not looking for a jquery solution I'm looking for a script or library that can just work without any library.

What I am looking for is an all-one script or drop in library that handles the complexity of using the best method of detecting a click, tap or touch events.

Comment: I've used hammjs and I agree, it's kind of overkill for just a tap. The only reason why I went with it is because it's dependency of angular material. Looking around on google, I ran across https://codeburst.io/the-only-way-to-detect-touch-with-javascript-7791a3346685 It might be helpful in demonstrating a 'vanilla' way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript equivalent of iOS's 'tap' event, but for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820863/javascript-equivalent-of-ioss-tap-event-but-for-android)

Comment: It seems strange in 2019 almost no one has a simple all in one click,tap touch detection library that just lets you do anyclick(callback) and handles the issues of tap, click, touch detection?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The SO question offered is for Jquery. Not going to load jquery to detect a tap event. Hammer is sub 8K

Comment: Noty sure why two down-votes. Lagit question. That clearly so far has not been answered.

Comment: The statements "I'm looking for a script or library" and "I am looking for is an all-one script or drop in library " make this question off topic for S.O.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to listen for a simple 'click' event you would use a JavaScript event listener. There is no 'tap' event in vanilla JS. Click should work for desktop and mobile.

[MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) on the subject.

It would look something like this:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // do something here
  alert('Clicked!')
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: He said it has to be native, so I would imagine something that only works in a browser and on a DOM element won't do

Comment: Ben, I'm not looking for how to write a click event. I want a robust all in one tap,click and hopefully touch controller that will drop into native JS and do all the hard work to make sure what ever the device the user has the event returned is the same IE anyclick(callback)